# CPU Credit balance stuck on maximum in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Our T2.small EC2 instance continues to do its usual 10-15% usage but the CPU credit balance has gone up to maximum and stayed there:

[image]
I have contacted AWS support but they just send me a link explaining how credit balance works. I know that this isn't technically a "problem" for us, but this is our important Production Server and it makes me a bit nervous. Has anyone had an issue like this with an EC2 instance?

Comment: That's a good thing and what you should expect to happen at 10-15% usage.

Comment: (Per [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits), a `t2.small` gets enough credits to sustain 20% CPU load.)

Comment: The AWS documentation is excellent. I suggest you read the material AWS support sent to you carefully.

Comment: I suggest you guys read the docs carefully too. A 10-15% Server load does not get you a constantly maxed out CPU credit balance. You have an overall positive credit balance, but not 3 consecutive days of 288 credits (the maximum for a T2.small instance). There are times in the last day where CPU usage has popped over 1 (1.25, 1.5) and still the CPU credit usage is stuck at 288 credits. This isn't right.

Comment: @Duncan. Good catch. I agree with you that something is wrong. Maybe in a positive way for the customer, I am not sure. I would test by creating a CPU load on the server for 10 minutes and then review the credit balance.

Comment: @DownVoter. Please add a comment on why you feel this question deserved a downvote and how it could be improved. I am upvoting.

Comment: I have seen exactly the same thing on my t2.micro instance; It has been pegged at the maximum CPU balance for the last week (with the exception of a couple of very minor dips under very heavy CPU utilization).  Will post back if I find out anything.

Comment: This AWS forum will help to use T2 as unlimited - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-t2-unlimited-going-beyond-the-burst-with-high-performance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER: From https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=5196 -

***Previously, earned CPU Credits had a 24-hour expiry period. Now, earned CPU Credits do not expire until the instance is terminated or stopped.***

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Tim! I will watch that thread like a hawk, I've also posted my own thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=267725

Comment: The change in algorithm has been confirmed: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=5196

Answer (score 1):

A `t2.small` instance type can use 20% CPU before it starts using CPU credits.

Your CPU is only using between 10% and 15%. Thus, you're collecting CPU credits faster than you're using them. Your credits will continue to rise until it hits the maximum, where it just stays.

To lower your CPU credit balance, start using more than 20% of your CPU.

You don't have a problem.

However, you could investigate to see if a `t2.micro` may work for your use case.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits

Comment: But the CPU Credit Balance is exactly the maximum. Constantly. Exactly. There are 2 things I am confused with:
1) The algorithm for counting credits hasn't change, and neither has my CPU usage, why are credits maxing out at 288 when nothing has changed? Has the CPU credit algorithm changed?
2) There are plent of 5 minute blocks where the CPU usage IS over 20%. So why has the CPU credit algorithm remained at maximum? I mean, it hasn't even dropped a single point.